# Parametric polar plot

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I have a function of a parameter $x$ that gives an angle, say $\theta=f(x)$ (not easily invertible), and I want to plot another function of $x$, $g(x)$, in a polar plot. How can I do it?

Comment: You may calculate some value pairs: {x,phi}, then invert them: {phi,x} and calulate an interpolating function.

Comment: Give an example of $f$ and $g$ or you will only get hand-waving answers.

Comment: Does `ParametricPlot` do what you need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `x` is in Cartesian Coordinate and `θ` is in Polar Coordinate, we need to use only one Coordinate.

### Method-1

Translate to Polar Coordinate. ( `x=r Cos[θ]`) and use `ParametricPlot` and `MeshFunction`.

```
Clear[f, x];
f[x_] = x*Sin[2 x^2];
x[r_, θ_] = 
  TransformedField["Cartesian" -> "Polar", x, {x, y} -> {r, θ}];
(*r Cos[θ]*)
ParametricPlot[
 r {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}, {r, 1, 
  4}, {θ, π/8, π/2}, PlotStyle -> Yellow, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 MeshFunctions -> 
  Function[{x, y, r, θ}, θ - f[r*Cos[θ]]], 
 Mesh -> {{0}}, Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 80, MaxRecursion -> 4, 
 MeshStyle -> {Thick, Red}]
```

[image]

### Method-2

Translate to Polar Coordinate. ( `x=r Cos[θ]`),use `ContourPlot` in `{r, θ}` coordinate at first  and then mapping to `{x,y}` coordinate.

```
Clear[f, x];
f[x_] = x*Sin[2 x^2];
x[r_, θ_] = 
  TransformedField["Cartesian" -> "Polar", x, {x, y} -> {r, θ}];
(*r Cos[θ]*)
reg = ParametricPlot[
   r {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}, {θ, π/8, π/2}, {r,
     1, 4}, PlotStyle -> Yellow, BoundaryStyle -> None];
polar = ContourPlot[θ == f[x[r, θ]], {r, 1, 
    4}, {θ, π/8, π/2}, PlotPoints -> 60, 
   MaxRecursion -> 4, PlotRange -> All];
cartesian = 
  polar /. {r_Real, θ_Real} -> r {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]};
Show[reg, cartesian, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

### Method-3

Translate to Cartisian Coordinate. (θ=θ[x, y],r=r[x,y])

```
Clear[θ, r];
θ[x_, y_] = Arg[x + I*y];
r[x_, y_] = Norm[x + I*y];
f[x_] = x*Sin[2 x^2];
reg = ImplicitRegion[π/8 <= θ[x, y] <= π/2 && 
    1 <= r[x, y] <= 4, {x, y}];
ContourPlot[θ[x, y] == f[x], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, {x, y} ∈ reg], 
 Prolog -> {Yellow, DiscretizeRegion[reg]}]
```

[image]